# Show/Hide multiple divs with single button/checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to achieve the Show/Hide for Multiple Lines as explained in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp
When I try this it only works on the 1st DIV element and not on the subsequent ones

My requirement is multiple buttons to reveal translations of a multi-line English text, line by line,

Eg.

> Button-1-: Show/Hide Spanish 
> Button-2: Show Hide German
>
> How are you (Always Visible)
>  cómo estás (controlled by button
> 1)
>  wie gehts (controlled by button 2)
>
> I am fine (Always Visible)
>  Estoy bien (controlled by button 1)
> ich bin ok (controlled by button 2)

and so on for multiple lines controlled by a single button.

Comment: Can we use bootstrap? It makes your button beautiful. You can highlight button which is active. Otherwise we have to use <input type="radio">

Comment: u could achieve it with jquery, with `toggle` or manually `.addClass('display','none')` and so on

Comment: @gpl - Bootstrap it is, button example will be helpful please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have understood you want to have multiple toggle buttons expanding/collapsing a div with some content.
So for this, you can have a single function with a parameter as language.

See the example below and run the code.

```js
function myFunction(language) {

  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(language);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

   if (x.item(i).style.display === "none") {
    x.item(i).style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.item(i).style.display = "none";
  }
}
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('Spanish')">Spanish</button>
<br>
How are you ? <br>
<div class="Spanish">
  cómo estás
</div>
<br>

I am fine. <br>
<div class="Spanish">
  Estoy bien
</div>
<br><br>

<button onclick="myFunction('German')">German</button>

<br>
How are you ? <br>
<div class="German">
  wie gehts
</div>
<br>

I am fine. <br>
<div class="German">
  ich bin ok
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ambrish, this controls only 1 line / 1 div at a time, I would like to control all divs with 1 button only, multiple lines of Spanish or German should show or be hidden by a single button.

Comment: @MikeBA see the updated answer. I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I would like to change this buttons to toggle switches / check boxes, how do I change the buttons to check boxes and call myFunction

Comment: @MikeBA Replace `<button onclick="myFunction('Spanish')">Spanish</button>`
With `<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction('Spanish')" name="Spanish" value="Spanish">
<label for="Spanish"> Spanish</label>`

Comment: How do I achieve by default display Spanish but German hidden and shown upon selection only?

Comment: Achieved the above with style="display: none" - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet:

```js
let spanish = document.getElementsByClassName('spanish');
let german = document.getElementsByClassName('german');
let selectors = document.getElementsByName('language');

function showLanguage(language){
    switch(language){
        case 'spanish':
        looper('block', 'none');
        break;
        case 'german':
        looper('none', 'block');
        break;
        default:
        looper('block', 'block');
    }
}

function looper(spanishVisiblity, germanVisiblity){
    for(let i=0; i<spanish.length; i++)
        spanish[i].style.display = spanishVisiblity;
    for(let i=0; i<german.length; i++)
        german[i].style.display = germanVisiblity;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="language" value="all" onchange="showLanguage('all');" checked>All
        <input type="radio" name="language" value="Spanish" onchange="showLanguage('spanish');">Spanish
        <input type="radio" name="language" value="German" onchange="showLanguage('german');">German
    </div>

    <div class="english">How are you</div>
    <div class="spanish">cómo estás</div>
    <div class="german">wie gehts</div>
    <br>
    <div class="english">I am fine</div>
    <div class="spanish">Estoy bien</div>
    <div class="german">ich bin ok</div>
</body>
</html>
```